awssdk.services.s3: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint
I have this piece of code:
    private String putS3Object(String objectKey, String mimeType, byte[] content) {

 S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1) // Set region to eu-central-1
            .build();

            log.info("adding {} - {} - to {} ", objectKey, mimeType, bucketName);
            try {
                PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                                .bucket(bucketName)
                                .contentType(mimeType)
                                .key(objectKey)
                                .acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)
                                .build(),
                        RequestBody.fromBytes(content));
    
                return response.eTag();
    
            } catch (S3Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            return "";
        }

but I have this error:
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: S3, Status Code: 301, Request ID: L75KCJ8A7K7WGQNS, Extended Request ID: BsqLF6F+HWW1CoEtVgZxe455hjsacpWCmWIXxwVFn7EnZgYleNPM7N818XYT8KP+8IpkWUA+iMOCRdgUFsy24438Q==)

and trying this is fine:
aws s3 cp pullpointer.svg s3://myxwaveq/

on the logs:
2024-12-17 17:10:32.233 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@connectSocket(366) - Connecting socket to myxwaveq.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.5.72.145:443 with timeout 2000
2024-12-17 17:10:32.257 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@createLayeredSocket(430) - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
2024-12-17 17:10:32.258 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@createLayeredSocket(431) - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2024-12-17 17:10:32.259 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@debug(84) - socket.getSupportedProtocols(): [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, SSLv2Hello], socket.getEnabledProtocols(): [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
2024-12-17 17:10:32.259 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@debug(84) - TLS protocol enabled for SSL handshake: [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, TLSv1.3]
2024-12-17 17:10:32.259 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@createLayeredSocket(435) - Starting handshake
2024-12-17 17:10:32.303 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@verifyHostname(465) - Secure session established
2024-12-17 17:10:32.304 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@verifyHostname(466) -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.3
2024-12-17 17:10:32.309 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@verifyHostname(467) -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2024-12-17 17:10:32.310 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@verifyHostname(475) -  peer principal: CN=*.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
2024-12-17 17:10:32.310 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@verifyHostname(484) -  peer alternative names: [s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, s3.dualstack.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.s3.dualstack.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.s3.amazonaws.com, *.s3-control.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, s3-control.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.s3-control.dualstack.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, s3-control.dualstack.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.s3-accesspoint.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.s3-accesspoint.dualstack.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.s3-deprecated.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, s3-deprecated.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, s3-external-3.amazonaws.com, *.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com]
2024-12-17 17:10:32.311 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.i.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory@verifyHostname(488) -  issuer principal: CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M01, O=Amazon, C=US
2024-12-17 17:10:32.314 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.internal.net.SdkSslSocket@debug(84) - created: myxwaveq.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.5.72.145:443
2024-12-17 17:10:32.340 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] software.amazon.awssdk.request@debug(84) - Received error response: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: S3, Status Code: 301, Request ID: V7kAQWWBTQ99YJKM5M12, Extended Request ID: VvTW1PA9XItafKTy7qGq7t3+vc98jiu5643yjPjUHjiW3FbDff1UtALT/L7KNt2/OXexiS6eVS2YaKuKeL3M/PN2MeSUW9Vjrfuotzyu)
2024-12-17 17:10:32.341 [scheduling-1] DEBUG [] s.a.a.h.a.internal.net.SdkSslSocket@debug(84) - closing myxwaveq.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.5.72.145:443
2024-12-17 17:10:32.343 [scheduling-1] ERROR [] c.m.service.ObjectStorageService@putS3Object(189) - The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: S3, Status Code: 301, Request ID: V127WBTQ9KLYJKM5M12, Extended Request ID: VvTW1PA9XItafKTl9b7qGq7t3+vcOyjPjUHjiW3FbDff1UtALT/L7KNt2/OXexiS6eVS2YaKuKeL3M/PN2MeSUW9Vjrfuotzyu)



Where does the s3 object comes from? You likely need to specify the region-specific endpoint when instantiating the client.

Please provide output of aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket bucketName . The exception that you have caught is usually comes when region is wrong

The log shows that the client connects to eu-west-1, not eu-central-1.

You don't have define the correct endpoint in your bucket S3 in your code.
Please modify to this :
S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
    .region(Region.of("eu-west-1"))  // Use the region obtained from the command
    .build();


Try using endpointOverride(URI) method to see if that fixes.
Format of a regional endpoint:
protocol://service-code.region-code.amazonaws.com 

Modify to this:
S3Client client = S3Client.builder()
                          .region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1)
                          .endpointOverride(URI.create("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"))
                          .forcePathStyle(true)
                          .build();

In your case:
protocol: https
service-code: s3
region-code: eu-central-1

References:

S3 Client Developer Guide Example
AWS Regional Endpoints


The issue must be with the region property, the aws-region you created your bucket and the aws-region you're trying to access must be different.
package test_mvn;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ObjectCannedACL;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;

public class S3Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(new S3Test().putS3Object("uploads/s3upload.csv", "text/csv", 
                Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/Users/sridharsivaraman/Downloads/s3upload.csv"))));
    }
    
    // NOTE: this should be available properly
    String bucketName = "test-bucket-sridhar";
    
    private String putS3Object(String objectKey, String mimeType, byte[] content) {

         S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                    .region(Region.US_EAST_1) // Make sure this is the region where your bucket is located
                    .build();

                    System.out.println("adding " + objectKey + " - " + mimeType + " - to " + bucketName);
                    try {
                        PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                                        .bucket(bucketName)
                                        .contentType(mimeType)
                                        .key(objectKey)
                                        .acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)
                                        .build(),
                                RequestBody.fromBytes(content));
                        
                        return response.eTag();
                    } catch (S3Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                    return "";
                }


}

this is a sample I ran from my local with the following output
adding uploads/s3upload.csv - text/csv - to test-bucket-sridhar
"c4030959207ba4d4512fa9a3103f83e4"

and public s3 URL https://test-bucket-sridhar.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/s3upload.csv with etag - [c4030959207ba4d4512fa9a3103f83e4] - same as one from output

Also, check the region in your terminal, it should match the one you're using in code.

